# How to link child pages in Wordpress to the parent?

Tags: wordpress

Odd question and maybe my logic is off on this one, but I have this structure in Wordpress:

- Page 1

  - Child page of page 1
  - Child page of page 1
- Page 2

  - Child page of page 2
  - Child page of page 2
  - Child page of page 2

In my theme I output this as one page per parent.

For example:

The layout is

```
<h1>title of page 1</h1>
<p>content of page 1</p>
```

After that a few small blocks:

```
<div class="box first child-page">
box with content of child page of page 1
</div>
<div class="box second child-page">
box with content of child page of page 1
</div>
<div class="box last child-page">
box with content of child page of page 1
</div>
```

But; now my problem! When someone uses the search box, The child pages, with their unique permalink are also shown, which is correct, but I need them to link to the parent page. Child pages should not be visited as a unique page, but the content has to be searchable (because, the content does exist on the webpage). Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to tell. I tried to 301 redirect the child pages to the parent page, but I need something easier for my client to be able to create child pages, and not having to worry about 301 redirects.

Regards.

Comment: It can be an automatic redirect from child page to parent page. But more elegant solution would be to have access to parent or child page without template problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get parent url you can do this inside the loop of child page

```
<?php
     $parent = get_permalink($your_child_loop_variable->post_parent);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this should be it :).